# How to remove some character from url using rtrim function in php?

Tags: php

code:

```
courses.php?search-result=sap+bo+training+in+india
```

In this code I am fetching data from mysql and now I want to remove training in india with due to this I am using rtrim() function in php like this:

```
$course_n = $_GET['search-result'];
```

Through this I can get the value from url i.e. (sap bo training in india) but when I am using rtrim() function it show me only (sap b) but I want (sap bo) and want to remove (training in india).

```
$course_n = $_GET['search-result'];
$course_name = rtrim($course_n,"training in india");
echo $course_name;
```

output:

```
sap b
```

So, How can I fix this problem ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `str_replace` "training in india"

Comment: `sap+bo+training+in+india` This Will be same in every situation ?

Comment: Check this snippet: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/645ca71288969b61cdbfe3589f3c8a9cbb7a2080

Comment: @AmitMerchant, [better one](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/172e79531c0b0c43a555ed85d4de1ebfc1d2f0d7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$course_name = str_replace("training in india",'',$course_n);
```

https://eval.in/979310

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove `"training in india"` in your string, better use `str_replace` like this

```
$course_name = str_replace('training in india', '', $course_n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example here is incorrect.

Second param in `rtrim` is not a string, it is character mask.

So, `rtrim($s, 'training in india')` is equal to `rtrim($s, 'traing d')`.

It's used by filter for trimmed characters.

I believe, you have used some character mask with 'o' character, and it was trimmed as well.

You should to select some other strategy to cut string from the end.
For example:

```
$str = 'sap bo training in india';
$cut = preg_quote('training in india');
$result = preg_replace("/\s*$cut\$/", '', $str);
var_dump($result); // "sap bo"
```